# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } when trying pass data to jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying pass data to jquery via `onclick`

There is jquery function:

```
function handleit(cId, anotherId) {
   var campaingID = cId;
   var another = anotherId;
   var post = "action=remove&campaign_id=" + campaingID + "&anotherid=" + another;
   $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "ajax/phphandler.php",
     data: post,
     cache: false,
     success: function(html) {
       $('#ready').html(html);

     }
   });
   return false;
 }
```

and there is `onclick` code

```
<td><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data='.$row2['campaign_id'].' value="submit" onclick="return handleit("'.$row2['campaign_id'].'","test")"></td>
```

rendered html

```
<td><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=43 value="submit" onclick="return handleit(" 43","test")"></td>
```

Comment: Where is that error thrown? What does `ajax/phphandler.php` return?

Comment: Since it's anyway a question about using the debugger, it's off-topic.

Comment: Post the actual, rendered HTML instead of whatever server-side stuff that is.

Comment: @FelixKling It doesnt return anything at all, button doesnt send POST or anything to jquery

Comment: @squint there is rendered html <td><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=43 value="submit" onclick="return handleit(" 43","test")"></td>

Comment: *"button doesnt send POST or anything to jquery"* Are you saying that the `handleit` is not called? How did you find out?

Comment: @FelixKling looked from IE developer tools network (all POSTS and stuffs comes there)

Comment: Ok. And where is the error thrown?

Comment: from chromes console

Comment: What is this weird practice to create a variable only because you want another name for the same value? Just name the function argument `campaignID` damnit! And `another`! Which is inconsistent by the way. Why keep `ID` in one and leave it out in the other one? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your HTML winds up looking like:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=foo value="submit"
    onclick="return handleit("campaign_id","test")">
                             ^           ^ ^    ^
```

When defining an attribute, you can't nest `"` inside `"`. The HTML would need to look like:

```
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data=foo value="submit"
    onclick="return handleit('campaign_id','test')">
                             ^           ^ ^    ^
```

How you accomplish that depends on whatever server-side language you're using, but probably involves escaping quotation marks:

```
<td>
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit"
    data="'.$row2['campaign_id'].'" value="submit"
    onclick="return handleit(\''.$row2['campaign_id'].'\',\'test\')"
</td>
```

Comment: Good catch. Doesn't explain the syntax error though.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually, it does: this is the error that gets thrown because of how the JS engine creates and evaluates the listener object.

Comment: Oh right, it will create something like `function() { return handleit( }`. I hate inline-event handlers....

Comment: @FelixKling Not sure if this behavior is defined by the spec, or just a quirk of the browser. Filed https://crbug.com/620026